# I'm making a screen capture window in python, but the capture is weird

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a program that captures the tk screen window with Python. I set the variables (x,y,x_end,y_end) to make the program, and I put the variable in ImageGrab.grab(), but the size changes to fit the window, but it is always captured at the same location.
How do we solve this problem? Thank you very much for your reply

```
def saveasImage():
    print("save as image")
    global im, tk_img, fname,out,img,x,y,x_end,y_end
    x=window.winfo_rootx()
    y=window.winfo_rooty()
    x_end=window.winfo_rootx()+window.winfo_reqwidth()
    y_end=window.winfo_rooty()+window.winfo_reqheight()
    img=ImageGrab.grab((x,y,x_end, y_end))
    fname = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.jpg')
    img.save(fname)
    window.update()
```

Comment: try using py-auto-gui, use pip to install!

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html, if you need to detect keystrokes unfortunately this won't work

Comment: @python_man it is possible to detect keystrokes using `keyboard` module

Comment: I don't know about the `ImageGrab` class but maybe the `grab` method asks for width and height rather than end x and y coordinates